# How to restore postgres dump

Tags: sql, postgresql

our developers have sent us a dump file from postgresql(file.sql) and we do not know how to restore it, we have already tried

```
psql -U <username> -d <dbname> -1 -f <filename>.sql
```

and received an error a 'superuser' failed to authenticate (by password)
what does it mean? should I enter the superuser of my laptop? Or is it a db user?

Comment: You should have a DB user or per default postgres as main user of your db, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with follow lines:

```
PGPASSWORD=password;

pg_restore --host "hostname" --port "port" --username "postgres" --no-password --verbose --dbname "dbname"  --schema "schema" "dump_filename";
```

where "hostname" is the hostname of the postgresql server (localhost), "port" is the port of listen postgresql server (5432), "postgres" is the username, "dbname" database name

Answer (score 0):

pg_dump does not dump users but it does their permissions. If the 'superuser' is being used to be set as the owner of some object, then you will want to create that user on your instance first. Since you are using `-1` it may fail when adding permissions to a user that does not exist. You could try `psql -h <dbhost> -U <username> -W -d <dbname> < filename.sql` that will run each statement in the dump and will continue even if it errors while setting permission.

Note: all objects will now be owned by the user you connected with.